# Error in adding Foreign key using Mysql workbench

Tags: mysql

Im adding foreign key to my table 'empcompensation' referring from another table 'employees'. It shows error.

```
ALTER TABLE `simhrmdb`.`empcompensation` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `Fk_employee`
  FOREIGN KEY (`employee`)
  REFERENCES `simhrmdb`.`employees` (`id`)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

> Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to
>   the database.
> ERROR 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign
>   key constraint fails
> (`simhrmdb`.`#sql-c5c_6`, CONSTRAINT
>   `Fk_employee` FOREIGN KEY (`employee`) REFERENCES `employees` (`id`)
>   ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) SQL Statement: ALTER TABLE
>   `simhrmdb`.`empcompensation`  ADD CONSTRAINT `Fk_employee`   FOREIGN
>   KEY (`employee`)   REFERENCES `simhrmdb`.`employees` (`id`)   ON
>   DELETE CASCADE   ON UPDATE CASCADE

i added the same 'id' from 'employees' table to few others table before and it worked perfectly. But now it creates error. Empcompensation table is the new table that i added.

In that error log, i can see some letters **#sql-c5c_6** . I dont understand this .

Comment: `#sql-c5c_6` is just an internal temporary table that MySQL generates to run the statement. Focus on the *Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails* part.

Answer (score 1):

This says that some of the values in the `employee` column cannot be found in the `employees` table. Find out what they are by using a LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT employee FROM empcompensation 
LEFT JOIN employees on employee = employees.id WHERE employees.id IS NULL
```

You will then have to figure out what to do with them (delete them, create corresponding entries in the employees table etc)

Comment: In other words, your current data already violates the constraint so you need to fix data first.